# sql UPDATE statement failing with SQL error

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

Keep getting this warning:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in string in query expression '' WHERE id = 86'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect

no matter how I edit this SQL UPDATE command:

```
$sqlU = "UPDATE inv20152016
        SET coNo = '$coNo', cusNo = '$cusNo', rcvTech = '$rcvTech', 
            rcvLoc = '$rcvLoc', rcvDate = '$rcvDate', rcyTech = '$rcyTech', 
            rcyLoc = '$rcyLoc', rcyDate = '$rcyDate', rtnTech = '$rtnTech', 
            rtnLoc = '$rtnLoc', rtnDate = '$rtnDate', cusInvNo = '$cusInvNo', 
            notes = '$notes
        WHERE id = '$rcyId'";
    if (!$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sqlU)) {
        echo '<br />Error UPDATE\'ing new record: (' . $sqlU . ')<br />';
        goto end;
    } else {
        echo '<br />RECORD successfully UPDATE\'d in database.recycle20152016<br />'; //$sqlUpdate<br />;
        header('location: searchDb.php');
        exit();
    }
```

After trying to submit UPDATE I get the following returned on the submit page:

> Error UPDATE'ing new record: (UPDATE inv20152016 SET coNo = '658454', cusNo = '3282', rcvTech = 'Dave Phillips', rcvLoc = 'Sparington', rcvDate = '2016-11-15', rcyTech = 'Melo Hazak', rcyLoc = 'Wildmere', rcyDate = '2016-02-16', rtnTech = 'Dave Phillips', rtnLoc = 'Sparington', rtnDate = '2016-02-25', cusInvNo = '', notes = ' WHERE id = 86)

It appears as though all the UPDATE vars are as expected, including the `id` in the WHERE clause. I have played with the quoting and spacing between vars without change. I have verified the data types in the ACCESS backend match the data being pushed for update.

Any ideas why this UPDATE statement might not be working?

Comment: If you can read the code, you can debug the code

Comment: Interestingly, your `WHERE` clause *id* value is wrapped in quotes but not in returned SQL.

Comment: Clearly here `notes = '$notes` there is a missing single quote at the end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You left a single quote `'` off the `notes = '$notes` columnId var.

Try:

```
$sqlU = "UPDATE inv20152016
        SET coNo = '$coNo', cusNo = '$cusNo', rcvTech = '$rcvTech', rcvLoc = '$rcvLoc', rcvDate = '$rcvDate', rcyTech = '$rcyTech', rcyLoc = '$rcyLoc', rcyDate = '$rcyDate', rtnTech = '$rtnTech', rtnLoc = '$rtnLoc', rtnDate = '$rtnDate', cusInvNo = '$cusInvNo', notes = '$notes'
        WHERE id = '$rcyId'";
    if (!$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sqlU)) {
        echo '<br />Error UPDATE\'ing new record: (' . $sqlU . ')<br />';
        goto end;
    } else {
        echo '<br />RECORD successfully UPDATE\'d in database.recycle20152016<br />'; //$sqlUpdate<br />;
        header('location: searchDb.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Date expressions must be wrapped in octothorpes:

```
rcyDate = #2016/02/16#
```